# tagName is null or not an object -- error msg in IE7 using latest version of jQuery (1.2.6)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

has anyone else seen this error message. a quick check with google doesn't show me much.

Comment: Give us a sample of the code that produces this problem - I bet jessegavin is onto something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry this was a sort of half-assed question, on my part. i'm going through my .js files and eliminating entire blocks of code now. i've isolated it to one particular .js file.

thanks all the same for reading through this question and replying.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to do something like this....

```
alert($("#myElement").tagName);
```

You should do this...

```
alert($("#myElement")[0].tagName);
```

Comment: alert( $("#myElement").get(0).tagName )  would possibly be the preferred syntax for your example.

Comment: The [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/get#index) say:

"This function called as $(this).get(0) is the equivalent of using square bracket notation on the jQuery object itself like $(this)[0]."

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you're running your script AFTER the page has rendered. If your script is at the top of the page and runs right away, and your DIV is below that script the DIV doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only seeing it in IE, it could be a bug with the DivX web plugin:

http://drupal.org/node/1038058

Issue is confirmed on the DivX site, which says "Fixed in the next release" (April 2011).

http://labs.divx.com/node/16824

Essentially, the bug is that DivX replaces the el.appendChild() function with an intercept that tries to lowercase the tagname, but doesn't bother checking to see if it is a text node.  This will break jQuery if you try to do something like `$('body').append('hi!')`. Additionally, it fails to return the element, which breaks SWFObject, for one.

The workaround is to make sure that you never call append() with a a text node, or with multiple top level elements.  If you are appending a series of items:

```
  append($('<div>hi</div><div>there</div>'))
```

make sure you wrap them in a top level div to avoid the implied text node:

```
  append($('<div><div>hi</div><div>there</div></div>'))
```

Here's a full workaround for `appendChild` being broken, the same approach can be used for `insertBefore` and `replaceChild` which share the bug.  The Divx JS is inserted some time after the page is loaded, so you may want to poll for this.

```
window.fixDivxPlayerBug = function () {
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    if ( window['ReplaceVideoElements'] && ! b.appendChildDivx ){
        b.appendChildDivx = b.appendChild;
        b.appendChild = function (el) {
            if( el.tagName == null) {
                var wrap = document.createElement('div');
                wrap.appendChild(el);
                b.appendChildDivx(wrap);
            }
            else {
                b.appendChildDivx(el);
            }
            return el;
        };
    }
};
```